# Irreducible Polynomial over the Rationals

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Question: Is $f(t) = t^4 - t + 1$ irreducible over the rationals?

My attempt: Is it valid to make a change of variables, letting $t = u + 1$? Then $f(t)$ has a root of zero, so the original polynomial is irreducible as well?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you can find a zero, then the polynomial obviously is not irreducible. But something seems to have gone wrong. Have you tried modulo two?

Comment: Whoops - I expanded incorrectly. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3):

Neither $1$ nor $-1$ are roots, hence $t^4-t+1$ has no linear factor. Assuming a factorization into two quadratic factors
$$\begin{align} t^4-t+1&=(t^2+at+b)(t^2+ct+d)\\&=t^4+(a+c)t^3+(b+d+ac)t^2+(ad+bc)t+bd\end{align}$$
with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$ (by Gauß lemma), we find $a+c=0\Rightarrow c=-a$, $bd=1\Rightarrow b=d=\pm1$, hence $-1=ad+bc=a(d-b)=0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ the reduction modulo $2$ of $f$. If $x \in \mathbb{F}_4$, then $g(x) = 1$ because $x^4 = x$.

But $\mathbb{F}_2 \subset \mathbb{F}_4$, so $g$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_2$ and in $\mathbb{F}_4$.

And, as you know, a polynomial of degree $d$ on $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is irreducible if and only if it has no roots in all the $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ for $r \leqslant d/2$.

So $g$, of degree $4$, is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

**Conclusion** : $f = X^4 - X + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you mention $\,\Bbb F_4\,$ : isn't it enough to show the polynomial is irreducible over $\,\Bbb F_2\,$ ?

Comment: @Don: A polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ has a quadratic or a linear factor, iff it has a zero in $\mathbb{F}_4$. That was quite a neat trick IMVHO. Of course, it is even faster, if you have memorized all the low degree irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$. My +1 has been there for quite a while.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, it is not like it is a great ordeal to memorize those low degree polynomials in $\,\Bbb F_2\;,\;\Bbb F_3\,$ etc., but you're right though not quite clear, for me at least, from what the OP, I think, did, in particular his 3rd-4th lines: I think he refers to the fact that an irreducible pol. of degree $\,d\,$ remains irreducible in any extension field of degree coprime to $\,d\,$ over the original field...

Answer (score 1):

$\rm g(x)=f(-x) = x^4\!+\!x\!+\!1,\,\ g(2)=19\:$ prime $\rm\Rightarrow\: g(x)$ prime, by $ $ [A. Cohn's irreducibility test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion)